# Saving an image on the mobile Android phone

Tags: android, file-io

I want to save an image that is received from an input stream to the device.
This image is displayed using an `ImageView` and the function `decodeStream()`.

How can I save the image received to a specific path (for instance, on the sdcard) on the mobile phone?

Answer (score 1):

To save to your external storage you can get the path like this:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
```

Then when you're starting a Camera intent use this, file location can be any path.

```
camera.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, [file location]);
```

More info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_OUTPUT

Comment: this is my code:
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStrea());
so how to add bmp image to the file location ?!

Comment: URL url = new URL(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + [File Name]);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

Comment: what is [File Name] ? the path or the name of the image ??

Comment: Although it is better if you put it in a folder of some kind

Answer (score 0):

make a bitmap also from decodestream say photo2

```
 mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
              Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "your apps name");   

 mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                 "Image" + num + ".png"); // make a int num and save it and
        try {                      //add it to the file name, increment for every
                                     //save that you do
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(mediaFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        photo2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,fOut);
```